# Redirect on another url without loading view if condition is false in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect

I am loading a page but page has a condition. If condition is false  I am redirecting url using $window.location.href on another url but before redirecting on another url default page view is showing first then redirecting another url thats not looking good. I am so confused what to do.Please give me any solution.

```
function get_bookings() {
    $http.post($scope.domailurl + 'api/class/booking.php?action=get_booking', { 'id': urlid }).success(function(data, status) {
        spinnerService.show('booksSpinner');
        if (data.ticket && data.ticket != "") {
            $window.location.href = $scope.domailurl + '#/attendeesprint/' + data.ticket;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you are meaning, but I do have a few suggestions that may help.

The first suggestion would be use the [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) service angular provides.  You can then use the following line instead of having to keep a $scope.domailurl variable.  However, I am assuming that this path is still within your application.  This may also fix your issues with the default page showing because you are no longer causing a full page refresh.

```
$location.path('/attendeesprint/' + data.ticket);
```

My second suggestion would be to move the **spinnerService.show('booksSpinner');** line to before you make the $http call.  This will make sure your spinner is showing during the asynchronous server operation.

Comment: I have to change fully url not assign in that view